# How to change this piece of code to receive result from a Thread operation?

Tags: android, multithreading, return-value

I have this piece of code running on Thread, for Android device. It was initially sufficient, but now I have a change in requirements that requires me to return the result after a HTTP POST. The "POST" function is in another class, so the code below will not work.

I read that RunnableFuture allows extraction of results for return of result. Can someone guide me on how to change this piece of code to that?

```
public ArrayList<String> addfood(final String status, final String spaceId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Add Food");

    final ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();


    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                String cookie = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(sURL);
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter(“status”,status)
                .appendQueryParameter("cookie", cookie)
                .appendQueryParameter("space", spaceId);

                String addresult = foodpost(POST(url, builder));
                results.add(addresult);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not the best solution but a workaround; have you tried creating a global variable that stores HTTP POST result? In the desired class you could wait until the global variable isn't null up to a certain timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

let me clarify you a pair of things:

Analyzing your piece of code you're trying to access to another method of other class (as you said in your comment) from inside of one thread:

> The "POST" function is in another class, so the code below will not work

It doesn't work because you have to have a reference to the other object in order to use the method.

But let me ask you a couple of things:

1. Concurrency is **hard** **(very hard)**. Even if after modifying your piece of code to use properly the `POST` method, have you ever considered what happens with that thread? What happens when the user decides to rotate the device? What happens when your `UiThread` (the thread responsible of updating all UI elements of your application) decides to read that list of resutls (is thread safe also?)? I mean there are a lot of considerations to take care before creating a thread to do some background operation. And trust me, is very easy to do things wrong. Maybe [it can leak memory](http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html) and your app may become an unresponsive one. Do you think is neccesary?
2. There are a lot of libraries that can help you to achieve that network request in a easy manner, carrying the weight of doing background things for you. Those libraries are very battle tested, it has a decent amount of user base. Libraries like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) are very good options to do whatever thing you want to achieve. So is there a need for not using that?

Sorry if I discourage you to use the thread, but there are a lot of useful options that would help you in the long run.